# Get column from a table dynamically on basis of input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure in which I will pass an id and I want to select a column on basis of it.

Suppose my table has columns namely - id, theme1, theme2, theme3, theme4, theme5 etc.

I need a query which will select the column on basis of my input. Like if I pass id = 3 then it should give theme3 column as result.

Is there any way possible for this type of dynamic query?

Comment: Which database do you use? E.g. Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL etc.

Comment: @user75ponic SQLServer

Comment: Yes, you can set your SQL statement in a variable and run it using sp_executesl  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Comment: Dynamic query is your solution look it up

Comment: Check my answer, please mark it as answer if it helps you

Comment: Is there a reason you want it to be dynamic in the way it gathers the column names, as opposed to writhing the SQL and checking the variable you pass in, to then select what you want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose my table has columns namely - id, theme1, theme2, theme3, theme4, theme5 etc.

If you can change this you really should...

Whenever you feel the need to set a **number to a column's name** (like `Tel1`, `Tel2` or `Theme1`, `Theme2`) this is a **very strong hint for a bad design**...

If possible try something like

```
CREATE TABLE Theme(ThemeID INT IDENTITY, ForeignID INT, ThemeRank INT, ThemeName VARCHAR(100));

SELECT *
FROM YourTable AS yt
INNER JOIN Theme AS th ON yt.ForeignID=th.ForeignID AND ThemeRank=@passedInValue;
```

To answer your question: The only way to do this is dynamically created SQL and I would really **not recommend it**! This is a very bad approach...

### UPDATE Just to be complete:

```
DECLARE @passedInId INT=3;
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT Theme' + CAST(@passedInId AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' FROM YourTable WHERE ...';
EXEC(@cmd);
```

This will create a SQL command dynamically and execute it. The problems are

- no ad-hoc / inline approach
- The usage of the retrieved result is - uhm - cumbersome...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you,
Ordinal_Position will help you to find the column details

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 2
```

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/183/informationschemacolumns/

Comment: After getting column name she can use dynamic query to construct the sql statements

Comment: But the OP **knows already** the column names... With `3` *passed in*  it should be `SELECT Theme3 FROM SomeWhere` and with a `2` it should be `SELECT Theme2 FROM SomeWhere`. Btw: The **ordinal position** of a column in a table's schema is something you should never rely on...